# ionic 3 DateTime component How to disable future saturdays and sundays

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

I tried creating an ionic form in which the DateTime component is used. I want to disable all future Saturdays and Sundays from the date picker. Is this possible?

My code is given below

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Select Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" min="2018-03-26" max="2020-10-31"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Please help?

Comment: Do you really want to do it using `ion-datetime` or any library is also fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is not possible to disable particular days (weekends/weekdays) using `ion-datetime` of ionic3.
Check out documentation for more functions and information:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

Alternatively, you can do it with libraries like this : https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker

Comment: Based on this documentation we are supposed to install this using bower. Is this possible for a mobile ionic framework application. Also how to add this in modules - angular.module('mainModuleName', ['ionic', 'ionic-datepicker']){
// 
}

Comment: @SunojVijayan, no you don't need to install using bower. You can download it and add it locally. Download this repository to your local and from `~/Downloads/ionic-datepicker-master/dist/` copy `ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js` to your project.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help so far. Much appreciated. I added the js in my assets folder. I added this in index file <script src="/assets/js/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script> . But how do i call ionicDatePicker.openDatePicker(ipObj1); in my .ts file. It will say not defined. Can you please point me to any tutorials if possible.

Comment: Also I am getting this error when I load the datepicker.bundle.min.js  -  Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined